# How can change the shape of output of rnn network?

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

How can change the output of `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` from [batch_size, max_stepsize, num_hidden]  to [batch_size, num_hidden]?

`self.outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, [-1, num_hidden])`  gives [batch_size * max_stepsize, num_hidden] but I am looking for [batch_size , num_hidden] and I don’t want to use  `tf.reshape(outputs, [batch_size, num_hidden])`. 
I tried `shape = tf.shape(outputs)[1]` and then `tf.squeeze(outputs, shape)` but it gives error:

```
TypeError: Expected list for 'axis' argument to 'squeeze' Op, not <tf.Tensor 'lstm/strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=int32>.
```

any solutions?

Comment: So the output shape [batch_size, max_stepsize, num_hidden] contains the output of each sample in the batch of each timestep and of each neuron of the state. So when you say you want the output shape to be [batch_size, num_hidden] I assume you only want the output of the final time step? If so, then you don't reshape, instead you select what you want

Comment: @user3631406 you mean this can be correct? outputs[:, -1, :] 

I am looking for the shape [batch_size, num_hidden]
Since later in loss calculation," losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=self.scores, labels=self.input_y)"  the first dimension of logits is not equal to batch_size, it is equal to batch_size* max_stepsize so I wanted to delete the max_stepsize from the output to solve this problem, not sure this approach is correct or not?

Comment: outputs[:,-1,:] would only work for a fixed number of timesteps and if your max_timesteps is exactly to the number of timesteps you actually do. tf.nn.dynamic_rnn should return the tuple (outputs, state) where outputs has the shape [batch_size, max_stepsize, num_hidden] as you mentioned. The state is the last hidden state, meaning the output of the last timestep, so you could just take that instead, which has the shape [batch_size, num_hidden]. And using the final output state and applying softmax to it is perfectly valid .